# Mouseover, mouseEnter

Tags: jquery, html

I have a FAQ and Question page. And if a user hover with his mouse over a question, then the answer will be shown.

But if you will now hover over a question all the answers are shown. what not has to be. Only the answere of the selected question has to be visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>A One Page Faq</title>
    <link href="Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.answer').hide();
            var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');
            $('.main h2').mouseover(function () {
                $('.answer').show();
                $answer.slideDown();
                $(this).addClass('close');
            });
            $('.main h2').mouseout(function () {
                $('.answer').hide();
                $answer.fadeOut();
                 $(this).removeClass('close');
            });           

        }); // end ready
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="main">
                <h1>A One Page FAQ</h1>
                <div class="faq">
                    <h2>I've heard that JavaScript is the long-lost fountain of youth. Is this true?</h2>
                    <div class="answer">
                        <p>Why, yes it is! Studies prove that learning JavaScript freshens the mind and extends life span by several hundred years. (Note: some scientists disagree with these claims.)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="faq">
                    <h2>Can JavaScript really solve all of my problems?</h2>
                    <div class="answer">
                        <p>Why, yes it can! It's the most versatile programming language ever created and is trained to provide financial management advice, life-saving CPR, and even to take care of household pets.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="faq">
                    <h2>Is there nothing JavaScript <em>can&#8217;t</em> do?</h2>
                    <div class="answer">
                        <p>Why, no there isn&#8217;t! It&#8217;s even able to write its own public relations-oriented Frequently Asked Questions pages. Now that&#8217;s one smart programming language!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, 3rd Edition, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

If I do it like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.answer').hide();
            var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');


            $('.main h2').mouseover(function (e) {
                $('.answer').hide();//Hide All Other Answers
                $(e).closest('.answer').show();//Show Closest Answer To Question
            });


            $('.main h2').mouseout(function (e) {
                $('.answer').hide();
            });
```

nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace this**

```
 $('.main h2').mouseover(function () {
     $('.answer').show();
     $answer.slideDown();
     $(this).addClass('close');
 });
 $('.main h2').mouseout(function () {
     $('.answer').hide();
     $answer.fadeOut();
     $(this).removeClass('close');
 });
```

**With**

```
$('.main h2').mouseover(function () {
   $(this).siblings('.answer').show();
   $(this).siblings('.answer').slideDown();
   $(this).addClass('close');
});
$('.main h2').mouseout(function () {
   $(this).siblings('.answer').hide();
   $(this).siblings('.answer').fadeOut();
   $(this).removeClass('close');
});
```

it will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way ;]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.answer').hide();

    $('.main h2').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).next().slideDown(300);
        $(this).addClass('close');
    });
    $('.main h2').on('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).next().slideUp(300);
        $(this).removeClass('close');
    });           

}); // end ready
```

```css
h2 {
    background: url(_images/open.png) no-repeat 0 11px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    h2.close {
        background-image: url(_images/close.png);
    }

.answer {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
        <header>

        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="main">
                <h1>A One Page FAQ</h1>
                <div class="faq">
                    <h2>I've heard that JavaScript is the long-lost fountain of youth. Is this true?</h2>
                    <div class="answer">
                        <p>Why, yes it is! Studies prove that learning JavaScript freshens the mind and extends life span by several hundred years. (Note: some scientists disagree with these claims.)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="faq">
                    <h2>Can JavaScript really solve all of my problems?</h2>
                    <div class="answer">
                        <p>Why, yes it can! It's the most versatile programming language ever created and is trained to provide financial management advice, life-saving CPR, and even to take care of household pets.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="faq">
                    <h2>Is there nothing JavaScript <em>can&#8217;t</em> do?</h2>
                    <div class="answer">
                        <p>Why, no there isn&#8217;t! It&#8217;s even able to write its own public relations-oriented Frequently Asked Questions pages. Now that&#8217;s one smart programming language!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, 3rd Edition, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you use class selector which actually select all elements has this class `$('.answer').show();`

you need to change your code to select the closest answer to the question and show it to be like

```
            $('.main h2').mouseover(function (e) {
               $('.answer').hide();//Hide All Other Answers
               $(e).closest('.answer').show();//Show Closest Answer To Question


            });
```

and for Mouse Out

```
$('.main h2').mouseout(function (e) {
   $('.answer').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I hover over a question nothing happens. See my update

Answer (score 0):

Use $.next(). Just now you're changing all classes .answer to be shown and all .answer to slideDown (within your $(document).ready() you grab the element from the whole document ($this) and later in code you run it)

Try this

```
$('.main h2').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).next('.answer').show();
    $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();
    $(this).addClass('close');
});
```

You should remove those two lines of code too.

```
$('.answer').hide();
var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');
```

And apply display: hidden; to your .answer CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.answer').hide();
    var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');
    $('.main h2').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.answer').show();
        $answer.slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('close');
    });
    $('.main h2').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.answer').hide();
        $answer.fadeOut();
        $(this).removeClass('close');
    });

}); //
```